# if statement is executed even when condition is false

Tags: unity

I've made some code that is triggered when the player is in range of the enemy. Everything was working fine until I tried to implement a condition when the countdown reached zero. I made a method (PlayerHit) that returns true if the player's melee skill is greater than a random range between 1 and 10 and false if not. I only want the enemy's health to be subtracted in the AdustCurrentBeastHealth method if the PlayerHit method is true. The problem is, the health is subtracted whether the health is true or false and I cannot understand where I went wrong. I have attached the script below.

```
private void AttackEnemy()
{
    //other code....

    if (playerCharacter.PlayerHit() == true)
    {
        Debug.Log (PlayerHit());
        enemyVitals.AdjustCurrentBeastHealth(-damage);
        attackTimer = Random.Range(1,6); 
        attackCoolDown = attackTimer; 
    }
    else
    {
        enemyVitals.AdjustCurrentBeastHealth(0);
        attackTimer = Random.Range(1,6); 
        attackCoolDown = attackTimer; 
    }
}

public bool PlayerHit()
{
    if(meleeSkill > Random.Range(1,10))
    {
        //Debug.Log(hitChance + "From block skill > hitChance condition");
        return true; 
    }
    else 
    {
        //Debug.Log(hitChance + "From else condition");
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Attach the debugger, step through your code line by line. You'll likely find that `PlayerHit()` returns `true` the first time you call it, then `false` the second time (in your `Debug.Log` call).

Comment: Learning to use the debugger will help you a lot in the future. You can easily solve problems like this on your own. I suggest you invest some time in learning how to use it. Also, programming questions that are not specific to game development (like this one) should be asked on stackoverflow.com instead.

Comment: They won't like this question either. StackExchange is for substantive questions about how technology operates, not debug your code.

Comment: well who can help me out if I get stuck?

Comment: I didn't know that the Debug would call the method again. I'm a beginner. I thought this forum was partly for people who are learning how to program and need help along the way. This was clearly a mistaken view.

Comment: If you didn't know Debug was calling it again, then there are some very fundamental things about programming you need to learn, like what a function call actually does. :) I recommend learning more programming basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if (playerCharacter.PlayerHit() == true)
        {
            Debug.Log (PlayerHit());
```

This code does not do what you think. It gets a new value when it does the Debug.Log, because the randomizer is called again.

You want

```
        value = playerCharacter.PlayerHit();
        if (value)
        {
            Debug.Log (value);
```